# Show that $\int_A f=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A - \underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A.$ Is my solution ok or not? (in "Analysis on Manifolds" by Munkres)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
The following exercise is Exercise 7 on p.133 in Section 15 in this book:

> Exercise 7. Let $A$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Let $Q$ be a rectangle containing $A$. Show that $$\int_A f=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A - \underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A.$$

I solved this exercise, but I am not sure my solution is ok or not.

The following is the definition of the extended integral of $f$ over $A$.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the (extended) **integral** of $f$ over $A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense). More generally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on $A$, set $$f_{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\text{ and }f_{-}(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$ We say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense) if both $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ are; and in this case we set $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-},$$ where $\int_A$ denotes the extended integral throughout.

The author made the following convention:

> **Convention.** If $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\int_A f$ will denote the extended integral unless specifically stated otherwise.

So, $\int_A f$ in Exercise 7 is an extended integral (an improper integral).
$\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A$ and $\underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A$ are ordinary lower integrals.

The author proved the following theorem on p.127 in Section 15:

> **Theorem 15.4.** Let $A$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Then the extended integral $\int_A f$ exists. If the ordinary integral $\int_A f$ also exists, then these two integrals are equal.

My solution is here:

> By Theorem 15.4, $\int_A f$ exists in the extended sense.
> Since $(f_{+})_A$ and $(f_{-})_A$ are bounded, $\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A$ and $\underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A$ exist. (in the ordinary sense.)
> By Theorem 15.4, $\int_A f$ exists.
> So by the definition of the extended integral of $f$ over $A$, $\int_A f_{+}$ and $\int_A f_{-}$ exist and $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-}$$ holds.
> We prove that $\int_A f_{+}=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A$ and $\int_A f_{-}=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A$ hold.
> To show $\int_A f_{+}=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{+})_A$ and $\int_A f_{-}=\underline{\int_Q} (f_{-})_A$ hold, we prove the following holds:
> If $f$ is a non-negative bounded continuous function on $A$, $\int_A f=\underline{\int_Q} f_A$ holds.
> Let $P$ be a partition of $Q$.
> \begin{align*}
> L(f_A,P)
> &=\sum_R m_R(f_A)v(R)\\
> &=\sum_{R\subset A} m_R(f_A)v(R)\\
> &\leq\sum_{R\subset A} \int_R f_A\\
> &=\sum_{R\subset A} \int_R f\\
> &=\int_{\cup\{R\mid R\subset A\}} f\\
> &\leq \int_A f.
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, $\underline{\int_Q} f_A\leq\int_A f.$
>
> Let $D$ be a compact rectifiable subsets of $A$.
> \begin{align*}
> L(f_D,P)
> &=\sum_R m_R(f_D)v(R)\\
> &=\sum_{R\subset D} m_R(f_D)v(R)\\
> &=\sum_{R\subset D} m_R(f_A)v(R)\\
> &\leq\sum_{R\subset A} m_R(f_A)v(R)\\
> &\leq\underline{\int_Q} f_A.
> \end{align*}
> Therefore $\int_D f_=\int_Q f_D=\underline{\int_Q} f_D\leq\underline{\int_Q} f_A.$
> Therefore $\int_A f\leq\underline{\int_Q} f_A.$